# Why can't I read or write registry keys/values from service

Tags: c#, service, registry

I created a service using C#. I installed the service using the Local Account. On startup the service is supposed to read and write keys/values to the registry. However, its not reading let alone writing any values to the registry.
I use the standard way of reading e.g . `Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Test\", False)`

Comment: Does the account have the appropriate privileges to do that?

Comment: Add a log file to your service and write there traces to know what's going on. Most probably it's a permission issue

Comment: Local System account or Local Service account?

Comment: local service. I even started the app as administrator.. still nothing